# Android how to change bottom navigation item color when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

```
bookAppoinmentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        MyapptsFragment myaaptsFragment = new MyapptsFragment();
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout,myaaptsFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    }
});
```

Here i am changing the fragment when button is clciked.I want to change the frament and also bottom navigation item color of that fragment when button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView#setselecteditemid)

> Set the selected menu item ID. This behaves the same as tapping on an item.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    bookAppoinmentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            MyapptsFragment myaaptsFragment = new MyapptsFragment();
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, myaaptsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
           ((MyActivity)getActivity()).changeMenu(R.id.action_settings);

        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

create one method in your activity like this

```
  public void changeMenu(int menuId){
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(menuId);
    }
```

than call like this in your setOnClickListener

```
myImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ((MyActivity)getActivity()).changeMenu(R.id.action_settings);

            }
        });
```

Comment: bottomNavigationView is in Activity.button clciklistener is in fragment how can i use that

Comment: how to use this line in adapter                 ((MyActivity)getActivity()).changeMenu(R.id.action_settings);

Comment: @deepa pass the context of your activity in adapter than use like this `((MyActivity)context).changeMenu(R.id.action_settings);`